# IDE Font spacing problems

Tags: c++, ide, dev-c++

A couple months ago, the font I was using in the NetBeans IDE suddenly had huge spaces between each letter, making it almost unreadable. (I was using the Papyrus font, which I modified to be monospaced; this gave my comments a hand-written look while still being usable.) I figured the spacing issue was my fault due to the modified font, so I simply changed to a different font. This worked fine, if a little less fun.

Now, I am using the Dev C++ IDE, as recommended for a class I am taking. I am once again getting the same problem here, only with *all* fonts. Does anyone know how to fix this?

- Is this a Windows 7 setting? (unknown; nothing has changed in Windows that I know of)
- Is this an IDE setting?  (possible, but it happened on more than one IDE)
- Is this a font problem?  (unlikely, as all fonts have the same problem)

#### Screenshots:

[image: font spacing problem]

This is what it *should* look like:

[image]

Comment: On first sight, the comments do not really look worse than the rest of the font. Looks like you are using a non-monospaced font with monospaced spacing, so the "smaller" letters have some empty space to their right. E.g. you can see the 'm' fits better than e.g. the 'i'.

Comment: Have your files suddenly got turned into Unicode files?  If so, all those spaces are probably`'\0'` characters.

Comment: @MartinBonner I think that is unlikely, why would all those `'\0'` be inserted in the first place? I also have the feeling that the compiler would not be too happy about that.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: If you have an ASCII (8 bit characters) file that is converted to UTF-16 (16-bit characters), and then you view it as ASCII, all the characters you are likely to find in a source file will look like like `'\0' 'c'`.  I can imagine Microsoft's compiler accepting UTF-16 files (particularly if they have a BOM at the start) - I don't know if they do.  Having said all that, I think you are right: It is a proportional font being displayed in the width of the widest character.

Comment: the NetBeans comments problem is not pictured above.  This is the more recent Dev C++ version where everything is spaced too far.  And no, my files have not changed to Unicode files.  As far as I know, nothing changed.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. I was able to solve this by changing the font family to **Consolas** under the *Tools* option in menu bar:

*Tools* -> *Editor Options* -> *Fonts* (Tab)

**Consolas** is the default font family for Dev-Cpp.

I believe font support for other families is a bit broken in some recent versions (I am using 5.11). Almost all the other fonts give me this spacing problem as well, but Consolas works just fine. It's pretty disappointing having to adhere to just one font, but everything else makes the code unbearable at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

On Dev-c++  go to tools,editors option, uncheck Cursor past EOL.   Hope this helps